# Is it bad practice to render a list of redux components?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have to render a list of products on my website using redux. Because I want each product to have state so that users can interact with them, I have made each product entity a redux component. However, when I dispatch an action on any of them, it runs the mapStateToProps function on all of them. If I had 1,000 products rendered, it would run through this loop potentially for any action (favorite, add to cart, etc...)

Is this bad practice? Practically speaking, I could let this loop run and it should be fine, even with 1,000 products.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might want to note that as per question guidelines, questions asking about whether bad practice, good practice or best practices are considered subjective and therefore may be downvoted by reviewers.

Comment: Lets say we have only one component which will show all products. Then we can have a reducer for selected product which will get a product and has multi action for that particular product.

Comment: Yes, that is one solution. It just makes things harder. It's nice to have a product that I can render anywhere I like. Instead of a horizontal list, maybe I just want to render them in a vertical line or something.